# Azure/Office 365 Migration from third party to AD Connect

Tags: active-directory, azure, migration, microsoft-office-365

We currently have Office 365 and our Azure Directory sync is managed by a a third party service who do not use AD Connect but their own API. Once we configure ADFS our end and setup AD Connect will this break all the accounts on Azure since they have already been populated from our AD or will this re-enable the sync again once we come away from third party and allow SSO?

Also, would there be an issue with setting up AD Connect before we come away from our third party as Azure will be retrieving the same accounts from our ADFS and our third party identity provider?

Thanks,

Peter

Comment: Seems like this question is best suited for the third party service, as without any insight into the API in use, the community would be hard-pressed to provide any definitive information

Comment: Ask the vendor what will happen to the Office 365/Azure AD accounts if you disable/remove their product/solution/API.

Comment: Hi the objects will continue to stay in Azure once third party has been decommissioned and they use objectGUID for stamping which I believe is the recommended way anyway.

Answer (score 0):

See there are 2 things to consider. AD Connect just sync the object to AzureAD. Your auth for the users is a whole different story.

What I am saying you can keep syncing your using your custom sync, and use ADFS for auth.

You can also break your current user sync and start sync users with AD Connect.

Comment: Hi our plan is to create our own ADFS infrastructure which we will do and test internally and externally prior to syncing with AD connect. It is looking likely that AD Connect will continue to sync from our network after third party decommissions.